# How to get the parameters from the Crystal Report

Tags: java, parameters, crystal-reports, report

I have a crystal Report with command as `SELECT * from Employee where EmployeeID = {?EmployeeID}` and I have some parameters, that is used in the report and the values are to be dynamically given.

Now in java, Using this code I am able to get only `EmployeeID` not the other parameters. So how can I get other parameters which are not used in the Command( the SQL query)

```
ParameterField commandParam = (ParameterField)  
command.getParameters().get(i);
```

Comment: Was this not helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915472/how-to-get-crystal-reports-parameter-names-with-java

Comment: This will retrieve the parameter list from the command(i.e, query). But I have custom parameters in the report which is not in the query.